# Error handler for multiple worker instances seemingly randomly triggered

Tags: javascript, web-worker, worker

Given I have a simple worker script:

```
// error_worker.js:

onmessage = function(event) {
  throw new Error('Error for ' + event.data.name);
};
```

If I’m creating multiple worker instances for the same script:

```
var worker1 = new Worker("error_worker.js"),
    worker2 = new Worker("error_worker.js");

function errorHandler(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  error.preventDefault();
};

worker1.onerror = errorHandler;
worker2.onerror = errorHandler;

worker1.postMessage({ name: 'worker1' });
worker2.postMessage({ name: 'worker2' });
```

The function `errorHandler` is seemingly randomly triggered. Sometimes for one of the two instances, sometimes for both.

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**

Should have tried this before, but just ran the test in Firefox and Safari and it works as expected. So this seems to be a Chrome bug.

The problem persists even after updating to the latest version of Chrome (30.0.1599.69) and seems to be platform independent.

I will file a bug with the Chrome team.

**UPDATE**

The issue over at the chromium tracker can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=307865&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: FWIW, I can verify your results (using Chrome on Linux). So it's not just you. :-) I **can't** verify those results on Firefox (on Linux), I always see the error from both workers (the order varies, of course).

Comment: And if I add a loop, posting multiple messages to both workers, sometimes I see all the expected errors, other times I see all of them but only from one worker, and *other* times I see some (but not all) of them from each worker. Separately: Updating the code to use `addEventListener` didn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve filed a ticket.